# I have this error: TypeError: TextIOWrapper.write() takes exactly one argument (16 given) when I code

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my project and I have a error in line 31 and 32

```
def sign_in():
sign = tk.Tk()
sign.title("Learn English To Study Abroad - LETSA  |  v0.0.1")
sign.geometry("300x210")

name = Label(sign, text = "Your Account: ").place(x = 0, y = 0)
email = Label(sign, text = "Your Fullname: ").place(x = 0, y = 20)
age = Label(sign, text = "Your age: ").place(x = 0, y = 40)
birth = Label(sign, text = "Your birthday: ").place(x = 0, y = 60)
email = Label(sign, text = "Your Email address: ").place(x = 0, y = 80)
phone = Label(sign, text = "Your Phone number (Optional): ").place(x = 0, y = 100)
password = Label(sign, text = "Your Password: ").place(x = 0, y = 120)
repassword = Label(sign, text = "Re-Your password: ").place(x = 0, y = 140)
e1 = Entry(sign).place(x = 85, y = 0)
e2 = Entry(sign).place(x = 90, y = 20)
e3 = Entry(sign).place(x = 60, y = 40)
e4 = Entry(sign).place(x = 80, y = 60)
e5 = Entry(sign).place(x = 110, y = 80)
e6 = Entry(sign).place(x = 175, y = 100)
e7 = Entry(sign).place(x = 90, y = 120)
e8 = Entry(sign).place(x = 110, y = 140)
btn_sumbit = tk.Button(sign, bg="light blue", fg="green", activeforeground = "red", activebackground = "light green", text = "Sign in!", width = 20, height = 2)
btn_sumbit.pack(side = BOTTOM)
# Ghi nhớ dữ liệu vào file .txt
with open('D:\VS Code\Bài code cuối khóa\info1.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(e1, "\n", e2, "\n", e3, "\n", e4, "\n", e5, "\n", e6, "\n", e7, "\n", e8, "\n")

sign.mainloop()
```

This is my error!

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: The error is quite explanatory. You have to concatenate all the string using ```+```. So it will all be 1 argument

Answer (score 0):

The commas: `,` are making each character separate arguments. But as the error states, `.write()` supports only 1 argument.

What you might want to do is use `+` to concatenate the strings to 1 single string.

Also:

1. `.place` and other geometry managers return `None`. So `e1,e2...` and other `tk.Entry`'s all are `NoneType`. So you need to split them up:

```
e1 = Entry(sign)
e1.place(x = 85, y = 0)
e2 = Entry(sign)
e2.place(x = 90, y = 20)

...
...
e8 = Entry(sign)
e8.place(x = 110, y = 140)
```

2. `.get()` method needs to be invoked to get the values of `tk.Entry` method

```
f.write(e1.get()+ "\n"+ e2.get()+ "\n"+e3.get()+"\n"+ e4.get()+"\n"+e5.get()+"\n"+e6.get()+"\n"+e7.get()+"\n"+ e8.get()+ "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
f=open('D:\VS Code\Bài code cuối khóa\info1.txt', 'a') 
f.write(e1, "\n", e2, "\n", e3, "\n", e4, "\n", e5, "\n", e6, "\n", e7, "\n", e8, "\n")
f.close()
```

Comment: That doesn't matter. It will still raise an error